# A JavaScript error occurs when loading a file

Tags: jquery

> Uncaught TypeError: `$.ajaxFileUpload is not a function`
>   The version of the jQuery JavaScript Library v3.2.1

Here is the code that shows the error:

```
function loadImage(field_id, component, target, target_id){

$(".ajax-loader").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
    $('#imginsert').hide();
})
.ajaxComplete(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});

$.ajaxFileUpload({

    url:'/core/ajax/imginsert.php?component='+component+'&target='+target+'&target_id='+target_id,
    secureuri:false,
    fileElementId:'attach_img',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status){
        $('#fileInputContainer').html($('#fileInputContainer').html());
        if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined'){
            if(data.error != ''){
                alert(LANG_ERROR+': '+data.error);
            } else {
                imageLoaded(field_id, data.msg);
                alert(LANG_BB_IMG_ADDED);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (data, status, e){
        alert(LANG_ERROR+'! ' + e);
    }

})

return false;

}
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Which jquery upload plugin did you use? Which version of jquery did you use? Check that loading of plugin perform after jquery.

Comment: The error indicates that, *at the time the code runs*, there is no function defined.  You either run your code before you include the plugin code or have not included the plugin code at all (or, there was a script error and it didn't load correctly)

Comment: How to know that plugin loading is performed after jquery